# VXLAN VNI VLAN mapping

Tags: vlan, tunnel, bridge, vxlan

Is VXLAN tunneling similar to Q-in-Q tunneling (except VxLAN works at Layer 3), such that each customer/tenant gets its own VNI and each VNI can then map to multiple VLANs, so a single VNI can encapsulate multiple VLANS. All examples on the internet give the basic configuration of 1 VLAN mapped to 1 VNI. The remote host also has the same VNI:VLAN mapping, so it receives the Layer 2 frames and forwards it on the correct VLAN.

Thanks

Comment: VNI:VLAN mapping is just for logical convenience. The VNI can exit into any VLAN beyond each VTEP. In other words, VXLAN does not know about VLANs, and does not carry any VLAN information.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

802.1Q or QinQ *tag*, they don't tunnel.

VXLAN tunnels MAC frames over UDP/IP (layer 4) between two endpoints (VTEPs), including a 24-bit *VNID* VLAN tag. You can usually map QinQ tags to VNIDs.

The VTEP pair provides a single logical link (P2P), so you can't run VXLAN on a flat network like Q or QinQ tagging.

See [RFC 7348](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7348) for details.